# アドネットワークのコンバージョンタグについて

Tags: javascript, cookie

nendというアドネットワークが用意している下記コンバージョンタグについて、質問です。

【コンバージョン計測ページに埋め込むjavascript】

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var tag_id = 99999999999999999999999999999999999;
var nend_domain = "https://s.nend.net";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s2.nend.net/js/nendRt.js"></script>
```

https://s2.nend.net/js/nendRt.js

```
if ("undefined" == typeof nend_domain) var nend_domain = "https://s.nend.net";
if ("undefined" == typeof nendRt) var nendRt = {
    init: function() {
        try {
            if (-1 != document.cookie.indexOf("nendoptout")) return 0;
            "undefined" != typeof tag_id && document.createElement("img").setAttribute("src", nend_domain + "/rt.php?tag_id=" + tag_id)
        } catch (a) {
            console.log(a)
        }
    }
};
var nend_user_agent = navigator.userAgent;
!navigator.cookieEnabled || (-1 == nend_user_agent.search(/AppleWebKit/) || -1 == nend_user_agent.search(/Android/) && -1 == nend_user_agent.search(/iPhone/) && -1 == nend_user_agent.search(/iPod/) && -1 == nend_user_agent.search(/iPad/)) || nendRt.init();
```

上記のjavascriptの中で、下記のコードが何のためのものなのかわかりません。

```
if (-1 != document.cookie.indexOf("nendoptout")) return 0;
```

nendopoutというkeyのcookieがある場合は、アドサーバーrt.phpに飛ばないようにしていると思うのですが、これは何を意図しているコードなのでしょうか？

こちらについて、どなたか解説して頂けないでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://nend.net/privacy/explainoptout で設定できるオプトアウト（ターゲティング広告の無効化）のためのコードだと思います。

実際に、上記ページの「無効にする」をクリックすると、cookieに`nendoptout=true`が追加されるのが確認できました。